# Monerod synchronization problems

Tags: monerod, synchronization

Monero noob here, my friend basicly did everything when he made me a wallet and stuff.

I had version "0.9-4-0", but it just froze and looked for blockchain. So i read some tips online, and downloaded "10.3.1" and deleted the c:bitmonero file.

Now i get this error:

Error: refresh failed: refresh error: block parse error.

Any guides or tips? Please go easy on me!

Comment: can you type the command status in monerod.

Comment: "Height: 1281590/1281864 (99.9%) on mainnet, not mining, net hash 62.04 MH/s, v4 (next fork in 9.8 days), up to date, 9(out)+1(in) connections, uptime 0d 0h 1m 28s"



                Do i have to copy my wallet files from the oldest monerod folder to the newest version or anything?

Comment: can you keep it running for a an hour to few hours then run type status command again. If you get 100% means everything should be running. No need to copy your wallet file since when you open CLI or GUI it will ask the location of the wallet.

Comment: I'm also having problems with the synchronization. it begins, but then I get this message at the bottom and it stops the sync: WARNING: no two valid MoneroPulse DNS checkpoint records were received. ive never done this before, but I'm clicking on monerod

Answer (score 2):

When ugrading from 0.9.x to 0.10.x it's highly recommended to delete the database and re-sync from scratch. You almost got it, but the default location of the database is in the c:\programdata\bitmonero directory not c:\bitmonero. Instructions below.

Make sure that monerod isn't running. Go to %programdata% and delete the "bitmonero" folder in that directory. Then try re-launching either monerod and use monero-wallet-cli if you prefer the CLI or launch monero-wallet-gui if you are a GUI user.

It'll take approximately an hour on a fast computer w/ SSD to download the entire blockchain, longer for a regular HDD, slow network, slower computer.

Answer (score 1):

That error is a wallet error. It is likely you're running an older wallet, which does not understand the new block format from the v5 fork.

If you were using simplewallet, make sure you now use monero-wallet-cli (it's the same program, it's just been renamed in 0.10.x).